# .htaccess rewrite function is changing all urls

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change my url so I used .htaccess 
I want to convert this link

```
http://example.com/editing.php?edit=56
```

to this

```
http://example.com/edit/56
```

I am using this code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^edit/([^/]+)/?$ /editing.php?edit=$1 [L,QSA]


</IfModule>
```

**Update**

Link is working fine but the content on the page is missing every image is missing because their link is also changed

if one image link was like this

```
http://example.com/image.jpg
```

it is changed to

```
http://example.com/edit/image.jpg
```

so image links are changed and not working because of adding `edit/`

Comment: Question isn't very clear. Can you try to explain a bit more.

Comment: Question edited see @anubhava

Comment: The rule you have posted would not have the effect you're describing; something else is going on. Please post your entire `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding this rule to fix image/css/js links:

```
RewriteRule ^edit/(.+?\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```